# Generate 9 Random Numbers among 1, 2,3 whose sum is 15

Tags: java, random, numbers

I need to generate 9 Random Numbers whose total is 15... And the Random Numbers must either 1 or 2 or 3 ...

Ex:

```
[1,2,1,1,3,1,2,1,3] 1+2+1+1+3+1+2+1+3 = 15 (9 Numbers Between 1-3 and sum is 15)
```

I need these kind of different lists through a program ...

I searched many programs but didn't meet my requirement ...

Thank You

Comment: Did you even try to write anything? Don't expect us to write the entire thing for you.

Comment: Where's your code? Also, if the numbers are random, there's no guarantee that they will add up to 15. Will you just keep generating combinations until you find one that sums to 15?

Comment: I Used `randomNumber = minNumber + (int)(Math.random()*(maxNumber - minNumber));` to generate a random number between 1 and 3 where minNumber is 1 and maxnumber is 3 ... But i am not able to get the logic how to get numbers so that the sum is 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate 9 numbers and store them in an array. Sum them.

Go through the array to achieve desired sum.

For each number if current sum is bigger than desired reduce number (if it's >1) if it's less increase the number (if it's <3) to achieve desired total.

Comment: Interestingly your method has a bias. Outcomes are more likely to have 3 ones and 6 twos than 6 ones and 3 threes. Mathematically one can show those two outcomes should have the same probability.

Comment: @user515430 it could be modified to multiple pass through the array increasing/descreasing by 1 starting from a random index of the array.

Comment: That's what I did. It still shows the bias. Repeating it 1,554,000 times I get 87707 of the former, 78333 of the latter. Expected values are 84000 for both. Here are a couple of more runs, 87514, 78374 and 87854, 78770. I'm using the Mersenne Twister as my rng. Seeded with a truly random value. I don't have an explaination why.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateRandomNumber() {
  Generate a number between 1 and 3
  while that number plus the total of the other numbers is less than 15, go to next random number, 
  while that number plus total of other numbers is more than 15, pick a new number
  if that number plus other numbers equals 15 , then 
     if there are 9 numbers, return the list, otherwise
     start at the beginning of the list and generate new numbers until there are 8 numbers adding up to a value within 3 of 15, then add the remainder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to the above problem by

`i . Add 9 1's to a list` and 
`ii . pick a number from list randomly` and `iii . If the number is less than 3 and sum of all numbers in list is  less than 15 then increase the number by 1` and `iv . Repeat this check until the total of the list is 15` ...

```
List<Integer> randomNumbersList = new ArrayList();

//Add 9 1's to the list

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    randomNumber = generateRandomNumberInRange(0, 8);
    number = randomNumbersList.get(randomNumber);

    if(number < 3 && getTotal(randomNumbersList) < 15)
    {
        number += 1;
        randomNumbersList.set(randomNumber, number);
    }
}

public int getTotal(List<Integer> list)
{
//Code to get total of the numbers in the list
}
```